# Highlight edge on Drawable in Android

Tags: android, android-widget

When i have an ImageButton and a drawable and i want to do something like the Drawer or Twitter where when i press the button and the corner of the image is highlighted over the edge, in drawer its yellow, in twitter its white. Like the one below.

[image]

How do i set my drawable without using a lot of images?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like just to replace one color of a Drawable with another in runtime you can try to modify a Bitmap directly. You can find a similar example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309629/how-to-change-colors-of-a-drawable-in-android).

But to my mind, using drawable XML resource with several Drawables for different button states is more likely to be an android way.

Regards,
Serge

Comment: is there a way to apply that to pressed event? and seems the image is not stretch when i do runtime.