# Android: Make specific (green) color in background image transparent

Tags: android, image, background, replace, transparent

i am writing an app for Android.

in an xml file defining layout I have a TabHost with 6 Tabs, which all have the same big background image "settingsdlg.gif".

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/settingsdlg" >
..
```

In styles.xml I specify that the window must be transparent:

```
<resources>
    <style name="my_app_style"  parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

The problem is that the background image "settingsdlg.gif" is a *rounded* rect, and the small areas at the edges, which should be transparent, are green.

I know that to use transparency in images on Android, the images must be in PNG format, and the pixels i want transparent should be saved in PNG as transparent.

Unfortunately I get the images from a database and I can't change them, because they are also used in some other application for Win32 and Mac.

Is there a way to tell Android that in the background image the green pixels should be rendered transparent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to change every green pixel into a transparent one. Here is an example: [How to change colors of a Drawable in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309629/how-to-change-colors-of-a-drawable-in-android)

However if there are green pixels in the middle of the image then you can have a problem. So the other way is, if your image has constant size and shape, to create a mask and use xfer modes to create a new image with transparent rounded corners.

Answer (score 1):

Just if anyone had the same problem, here is the code:

```
//remove green edges from bg image
    Bitmap bgBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.settingsdlg)).getBitmap();
    Bitmap transparentBgBitmap = Utils.getBitmapWithTransparentBG(bgBitmap, Color.GREEN);
    tabHost.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(transparentBgBitmap));
```

in Utils:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapWithTransparentBG(Bitmap srcBitmap, int bgColor) {
    Bitmap result = srcBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    int nWidth = result.getWidth();
    int nHeight = result.getHeight();
    for (int y = 0; y < nHeight; ++y)
      for (int x = 0; x < nWidth; ++x) {
    int nPixelColor = result.getPixel(x, y);
    if (nPixelColor == bgColor)
      result.setPixel(x, y, Color.TRANSPARENT);
      }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet worked for me:

```
PorterDuffColorFilter porterDuffColorFilter = new PorterDuffColorFilter(
    getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color),
    PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY
);
imgView.getDrawable().setColorFilter(porterDuffColorFilter);
imgView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```