# How to remove white background color from BitmapDrawable or bitmap image in android?

Tags: android, masking, imagefilter

I want to remove the white background color in a bitmap like in this example image.

**This is my first try**:

```
BitmapDrawable drawableImg = getImage();
drawableImg.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.WHITE,
PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OUT));
```

**Second try**:

To remove the white colors range by setting fromBgColor and toBgColor, But when I replace the color with android transparent color the image turns into black here is the code:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapWithTransparentBG(Bitmap srcBitmap, 
       int fromBgColor, int toBgColor) {
    Bitmap result = srcBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    int nWidth = result.getWidth();
    int nHeight = result.getHeight();
    for (int y = 0; y < nHeight; ++y)
        for (int x = 0; x < nWidth; ++x) {
            int nPixelColor = result.getPixel(x, y);
            if (nPixelColor >= fromBgColor && nPixelColor <= toBgColor)
                result.setPixel(x, y, Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    return result;
}
```

**Hint** I had a hint that bitmap does not support transparent bits and I should use PNG or Gif instead of bitmaps is that right?

**Hint 2** It turned out that bitmap in Android has an option to show transparency since API level 1 using Bitmap.Config enum. Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config) in the documentation of Android.

[image]

Comment: hi @khaled, did you found any solution for this. I am searching for the solution and need to convert white background after masking to transparent.

Comment: Nope. But now I know that to do this I'll need to draw PNG not bitmaps as bitmaps do not support having transparent backgrounds.

Comment: hey @khaled,thanks for reply. But I am not understanding your view how would you draw PNG and not bitmap. If possible could you guide me more how would you do this. As I am stuck with this issue since long,and did not find any solution of it.

Comment: hey @khaled, I have same issue which is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502946/remove-white-background-from-masked-image-in-android. Could you please help me in this, Is it possible to remove white background from image in android.

Answer (score 0):

what is beneath your image? Maybe it could be a layout issue. Have you tried setting android:background="@android:color/transparent" in the xml?
I see you tried the getBitmapWithTransparentBG described in
[Android: Make specific (green) color in background image transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155999/android-make-specific-green-color-in-background-image-transparent)
But have you tried also this?
[How to change colors of a Drawable in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309629/how-to-change-colors-of-a-drawable-in-android)
About the image being jpg or png, I've managed to work with both after loading and setting it to a imageview (getting the bitmap back from it), and it allows to set the transparency using the getBitmapWithTransparentBG function as quoted above.

Comment: in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309629/how-to-change-colors-of-a-drawable-in-android this answer could work if you want to give it any color but transparent. As bitmaps does not have the concept of transparency. I don't know in the latest SDKs if there is a png drawable or not. But I need PNGs to support transparent color. I shall check and return back to you.