# Removing Image Background Android

Tags: android

I am working on an Image editing app, I have done almost everything that is cropping, re-sizing, filters e.t.c but I cannot seem to really figure out how I can remove image background,the basic idea is the image will have a distinct background e.g subject can be grey and background white or vice versa, I tried looking up here and other sites but could not really find anything matching my description the closest thing was to use OpenCV which did not really do the job well, for the most part it was slow (using GrabCut), if anyone has tried this before or knows how to please help thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can iterate over your bitmap through all pixels. And check if pixel color value is near in color value of your established background color. And change those pixel color values to transparent etc.

Edit: [this answer may be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5165976/1051804)

Comment: that truly helped though am guessing another slow method, but I will have to compress the image and run the background removal on another thread that should solve it thanks