# Changing only a certain part of a Drawable dynamically

Tags: android, android-view

I have a View with a ShapeDrawable as its background, and I want to be able to change only the background color (the "solid" part) of the Drawable, without changing the other part (such as "stroke"). Is there a way to accomplish that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: Actually in my case I have defined the drawable as an XML file, and Android converted it to a GradientDrawable object, not a ShapeDrawable, so I cast it to its RTT (run-time type), and then used its setColor function:

```
GradientDrawable colorBackground=(GradientDrawable)currentColorView.getBackground();
colorBackground.setColor(color);
```

As I said, it works only for GradientDrawable, so for other drawable types, another way must be searched.

Answer (score 0):

How about setColorFilter().

You can use that in combination with invalidate() so that the drawable gets redrawn. Take a look at these links for reference

[ShapeDrawable colorfilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable.html#setColorFilter%28android.graphics.ColorFilter%29)

[Drawable InvalidateSelf](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#invalidateSelf%28%29)

I also came across a nice post on stack. Take a look at this as well.
[How to change colors of Android drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309629/how-to-change-colors-of-a-drawable-in-android)