# Android Dynamic rich background

Tags: android, background

For a personnal app where the user will be able to draw on a whiteboard, I need to have a dynamic background on an icon.

It's a kind of paint bucket where the user will be able to select the color of his choice. Basically, when the user clicks on the button, a color picker dialog appears and he can select one. I need the icon background to change with the given color.

My button looks like that:
[image]

I need the red color to change to the new one when the user has clicked on the valid button in my dialog. And to add a border on that button after to tell the user this option is selected.

Is there a way to do that programmaticlly or not ? If so how ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look to [Drawable#setColorFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#setColorFilter%28int,%20android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode%29).

You can actually use:

```
Drawable.setColorFilter( 0xffff0000, Mode.MULTIPLY ).
```

This set white pixels to red, where the color format is ARGB.

If it wont work try a more brute solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1715673/821054

Comment: Thank you very much. It should do the job!