# How to dynamically change notification icon color?

Tags: android

I use several hundred drawables within my app to dynamically display data with a notification icon in the status bar. Each is a PNG consisting of white text and a transparent background. I would like to change the white to another color in certain situations, but it seems like there must be a better way to do so other than re-creating hundreds of identical icons in different colors. Is it possible to do this with code?

I have found methods to change the color of a `Drawable` (ie: [How to change colors of a Drawable in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309629/how-to-change-colors-of-a-drawable-in-android)), but cannot figure out how to apply this to a notification icon. `NotifBuilder.setSmallIcon()` calls for an `int`, not a `Drawable`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it could work with a [LevelListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LevelListDrawable.html) combined with a [LayerDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html):

> **LevelListDrawable** : A resource that manages a number of alternate Drawables, each assigned a maximum numerical value. Setting the level value of the object with setLevel(int) will load the image with the next greater or equal value assigned to its max attribute. A good example use of a LevelListDrawable would be a battery level indicator icon, with different images to indicate the current battery level.
>
> **LayerDrawable** : A Drawable that manages an array of other Drawables. These are drawn in array order, so the element with the largest index will be drawn on top.

Try this:

- a LevelListDrawable XML that contains as many levels as colors (e.g. level 1 = red, level 2 = blue etc)
- each level references a LayerDrawable that contains 2 items, the background color 1st, the PNG icon last
- repeat for all your icons
- when you build the Notification, set the [iconLevel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#iconLevel) property on the Notification object to the value that corresponds to the color you want

You'd still have many XML drawables, but that's more dynamic than a separate PNG for each icon/color combination.

Comment: Interesting thought, although I am already using both of these methods so I'm not sure if it would work. The `LevelListDrawable` controls which numerical value is shown (mobile signal strength in dB), and the `LayerDrawable` overlays a piece of text above it (connection type). I was also looking to change the icon color, not the background color -- but this may lead me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Colors should NOT be used for notification icons, that are expected not to have colors. [1]

Colored icons may work on some older Android versions, but will not work on newer platforms. [2]

[1] http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#notification

[2] https://developer.android.com/preview/notifications.html#guidelines , see the DO and DON'T under "Use distinct icons" section

Comment: I am familiar with the Android iconography guidelines, and have adhered to them to this point; user demand is dictating otherwise and I'm considering a change. I'm asking for the technical know-how, not Google policy. There are many popular apps that use colored icons -- that doesn't necessarily make it right, but that's not the point of my question.

Comment: probably my answer should have been a comment, then. :)

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
  mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // Sets an ID for the notification, so it can be updated
    int notifyID = 1;
    mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle("New Message")
    .setContentText("You've received new messages.")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify_status)
    numMessages = 0;
    // Start of a loop that processes data and then notifies the user
    ...
    mNotifyBuilder.setContentText(currentText)
    .setNumber(++numMessages);
    // Because the ID remains unchanged, the existing notification is
    // updated.
    mNotificationManager.notify(
    notifyID,
    mNotifyBuilder.build());
    ...
```

See http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/managing.html

Comment: This is just a direct paste of the notification example from the AOSP website. It does not answer the question at all.