# Change png icon color in from drawable resources

Tags: android, icons, png, android-drawable

I have a png icon in drawable. It's black with the transparent background.

How can I change the icon color without adding another drawable?

Comment: Go paint and inverse it

Comment: Without paint ))))) Only in the android

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5837189/6097062

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change colors of a Drawable in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309629/how-to-change-colors-of-a-drawable-in-android)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a [ColorFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorFilter.html) to change the icons color at runtime.

Try something like this:

```
    Drawable mIcon= ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.your_icon);
    mIcon.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.new_color), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    mImageView.setImageDrawable(mIcon);
```

Answer (score 5):

A good helper function for this is,

```
public Drawable getTintedDrawable(Resources res,
    @DrawableRes int drawableResId, @ColorRes int colorResId) {
    Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(drawableResId);
    int color = res.getColor(colorResId);
    drawable.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    return drawable;
}
```

[Fast Android asset theming with ColorFilter - Dan Lew](http://blog.danlew.net/2014/08/18/fast-android-asset-theming-with-colorfilter/)

Answer (score 2):

```
Drawable mDrawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.balloons); 
mDrawable.setColorFilter(new 
PorterDuffColorFilter(0xffff00,PorterDuff.Mode.LIGHTEN));
```

Try the above You can Play with          PorterDuffColorFilter(0xffff00,PorterDuff.Mode.LIGHTEN)
     You can use Black etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this static method:

```
public static Drawable changeDrawableColor(Drawable drawable, int color) {
    drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
    DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, color);
    return drawable;
}
```

The color parameter could be a color from your resources.

Answer (score 1):

`PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN`

Using this property you change the color of the icon with the exact color chosen.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        Drawable mIcon= ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.icon_send);
        mIcon.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        ibSendMessage.setBackground(mIcon);
}
```

In newer versions of Android you can do this in XML

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
```

Comment: `backgroundTint` didn't work for me, currently using Android Studio 4.0

Answer (score 1):

If you change "Drawable" other 'ImageView's that use this "Drawable resource" will also change, it is better to apply the filter to single "ImageView".

Using these two functions, you can enter the color you want as an ID (like: R.color.white) or color code (like: #efec0c).

```
public void ChangePngIconColor(String Target_Color, ImageView Target_ImageView){
    
    /*
     * Sample: 
     * Target_Color = "#efec0c"; OR Target_Color = "efec0c";
     * 
     */
    
    Target_Color = (Target_Color.startsWith("#")) ? Target_Color : "#"+Target_Color;
    
    Target_ImageView.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor(Target_Color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
}


public void ChangePngIconColor(int Target_Color_ID, ImageView Target_ImageView){
    
    /*
     * Sample: Target_Color = R.color.white;
     * 
     */
    
    Target_ImageView.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context,Target_Color_ID), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Kotlin extension function on `Resources` without deprecation:

```
fun Resources.tintedDrawable(
    @DrawableRes drawableResId: Int, @ColorRes colorResId: Int
): Drawable? {
    val drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(this, drawableResId, null)
    val color = ResourcesCompat.getColor(this, colorResId, null)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
        drawable?.colorFilter = BlendModeColorFilter(color, BlendMode.SRC_IN)
    else
        drawable?.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
    return drawable
}
```

Usage in activity:

```
resources.tintedDrawable(R.drawable.my_drawable, R.color.my_tint)
```