# SetColorFilter is not working in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

```
var upArrow = Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material);
upArrow.SetColorFilter(Resources.GetColor(Android.Resource.Color.White), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn);
SupportActionBar.SetHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
```

The above code does not change the arrow color. upArrow ColorFilter value is null. What should be the reason for this? I'm not asking how to change the drawable color. My question is why the above code fails to set the color filter? Following is the MainActivity code.

```
public class MvxFormsApplicationActivity : FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle); ;
        //Plugins.NewictLib.Forms.Android.Renderers.GifImageViewRenderer.Init ();
        DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.FlowListView.Init ();
        UserDialogs.Init ((Activity) Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context);

        OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PlotViewRenderer.Init();

        //            var mvxFormsApp = new MvxFormsApp ();
        //            LoadApplication (mvxFormsApp);
        var myApp = new MyFormsApp();
        LoadApplication (myApp );
        AppCompatDelegate.CompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled = true;
        //the following needs to set so that the back button color can be changed
        var upArrow = Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material);
        upArrow.SetColorFilter(Resources.GetColor(Android.Resource.Color.White), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn);
        SupportActionBar.SetHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);

               if (IsPlayServicesAvailable())
        {
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(RegistrationIntentService));
            StartService(intent);
        }
        //var presenter = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewPresenter>() as MvxFormsDroidMasterDetailPagePresenter;
        var presenter = Mvx.Resolve <IMvxViewPresenter> () as MVxFormsDroidCustomPagePresenter;//MvxFormsDroidPagePresenter;
        if ( presenter == null ) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException (nameof(presenter), "MvxFormsApplicationActivity: Please check your Activity class and ensure the presenter has value");
        }
        //presenter.MvxFormsApp = mvxFormsApp;
        presenter.MvxFormsApp = oznesFormsApp;
        Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>().Start();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change colors of a Drawable in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309629/how-to-change-colors-of-a-drawable-in-android)

Comment: @Cheesebaron No! It's not about how, it's about why it's not working.

Comment: "upArrow ColorFilter value is null.", I used your code for testing, it's not null by my side. What is your android target version?

Comment: It was Android 7.1. I changed it to Android 6.0 after you asked but the result is same.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a minimal sample demonstrating `SetColorFilter` working on a Android 7.1 and Android 6.0 emulator.

**MainActivity.cs**

```
[Activity(Label = "App39", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        var upArrow = AppCompatResources.GetDrawable(this, Resource.Drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material);
        upArrow.SetColorFilter(new Color(ContextCompat.GetColor(this, Android.Resource.Color.HoloBlueBright)), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn);
        SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        SupportActionBar.SetHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);

        Button b = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button);
        b.Click += B_Click;
    }

    private void B_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        StartActivity(i);
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="App39.App39" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
  <application android:label="App39" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"></application>
</manifest>
```

What's the difference between my code and your code?

You're using two deprecated methods which in reality, you should be using the Support library equivalent. Such as `ContextCompat.GetColor`. Secondly you should be using the `AppCompatResources` or `ResourcesCompat` `GetDrawable` method instead of `Resources.GetDrawable`.

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/content/res/AppCompatResources.html#getDrawable(android.content.Context, int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/content/res/AppCompatResources.html#getDrawable(android.content.Context,%20int))

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat.html#getDrawable(android.content.res.Resources, int, android.content.res.Resources.Theme)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat.html#getDrawable(android.content.res.Resources,%20int,%20android.content.res.Resources.Theme))

[image: Android API 25]

Comment: My main activity derives from FormsAppCompatActivity and it gives the following error when I try your code. Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='getDrawable' signature='(I)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;' in class Landroid/content/Context;

Comment: Make sure you are compiling >= API 21:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDrawable(int)

Comment: I've updated the question with more code. Please have a look.

Comment: Min Android version is 4.0.3 (API Level 15), Target android version - Use Compile using SDK version, Compile using Android version is (Android 7.1 Nougat)

Comment: What emulator API level are you running this on? If you run it on < 21, it will fail because the method doesn't exist on that level. Perhaps you're better off using `ResourcesCompat.GetDrawable` or `AppCompatResources.GetDrawable`. Updated my code to reflect that.

Comment: I'm using two real devices (API 19 and API 22). In both I see the same result.

Comment: I ran this code on API 19 and API 23 and it works just fine. Did you use my updated code?

Comment: I used your updated code. Maybe something is wrong with the project I guess. I'm not even setting the BarTextColor or BarBackgroundColor anywhere though. Arrow is always black no matter what I do.

Comment: The problem is that you are using Forms which adds an extra layer of abstraction which is probably setting the value to a default. If you had originally tagged this question as Forms, I'm sure one would have a better answer than mine. Mine works in Native Xamarin.Android in most scenarios.