# How to get and change drawable background color in custom view

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have a custom view which extends TextView and the background is a drawable,

```
<CustomView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/circile_background" />
```

and want to change the background color in custom view

```
public class CustomView extends TextView {

    TypedArray typedArray;

    public CustomView (Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }


    public void setColorLevel(int color) {
       // update color here
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to keep both background image and color...?

Comment: Thanks . Yes, I want keep the image and just change the imagecolor

Comment: `getBackground().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC);`

Comment: @MikeM Thank so much it works.

Comment: No problem. It looks like svkaka posted an answer below with the same idea. If it helped, you might consider accepting it. Feel free to ask them to edit it a bit, if maybe `MULTIPLY` isn't the exact effect you're looking for. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check similar question here [How to change colors of a Drawable in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309629/how-to-change-colors-of-a-drawable-in-android)

```
public void setDangerLevel(int color) {
    Drawable drawable=this.getBackground().getCurrent();
    drawable.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    }
```