# Remove Background of an Image, Split it in same sizes and Change color(overlay)

Tags: android, canvas, paint

I've been searching the internet for changing colour or overlaying a specific part of a bitmap. I've a square bitmap and I want to change the colour in a matrix pattern that is in equal 9 blocks which can be understood from the following image. (Cyan colour line here is for demonstration only)
[image]

I've read about boundary fill algorithm in College but here for java, I came to know that it is too bulky to perform such an operation for 9 specific parts. And I don't know how to use `Paint` with `Canvas` for such a square scenario.

So is there a method or something which can help me figure out how to paint a specific square by providing the size or location without performing a huge task on UI.

Here's what I need to achieve:

[image]

I can change the color, location,size by myself if there's something which can help me out. 
Also, as there is white background, is there a way to not paint the background or do I have to use PNG?

Update:

I'm successfully able to divide the image in 9 equal parts using following code but `PorterDuffColorFilter` is not working as expected.

Code:

```
public void splitBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        int width, height;
        // Divide the original bitmap width by the desired vertical column count
        width = bitmap.getWidth() / 3;
        // Divide the original bitmap height by the desired horizontal row count
        height = bitmap.getHeight() / 3;
        // Loop the array and create bitmaps for each coordinate
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; ++x) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 3; ++y) {
                // Create the sliced bitmap
                smallimages.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, x * width, y * height, width, height));
            }
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

The above code provides 9 bitmaps which then set to a `GridLayout`. But No mode of `PorterDuffColorFilter` is useful. Either the images remain original or is painted completely. I've tried every one of the modes available and none worked.

Comment: @pskink I've tried it but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar to this so after changing my code a bit, I think this is what you want:

Assuming that you don't have PNG,

First, remove the white background from your image [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1715673/8244632):
Setting the white color as Transparent, you can use any color you want.

```
private static final int[] FROM_COLOR = new int[]{255, 255, 255};
private static final int THRESHOLD = 3;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_colors);

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
    Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(RES);
    iv.setImageDrawable(adjust(d));
}

private Drawable adjust(Drawable d)
{
    int to = Color.TRANSPARENT;

    //Need to copy to ensure that the bitmap is mutable.
    Bitmap src = ((BitmapDrawable) d).getBitmap();
    Bitmap bitmap = src.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    for(int x = 0;x < bitmap.getWidth();x++)
        for(int y = 0;y < bitmap.getHeight();y++)
            if(match(bitmap.getPixel(x, y))) 
                bitmap.setPixel(x, y, to);

    return new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
}

private boolean match(int pixel)
{
    //There may be a better way to match, but I wanted to do a comparison ignoring
    //transparency, so I couldn't just do a direct integer compare.
    return Math.abs(Color.red(pixel) - FROM_COLOR[0]) < THRESHOLD &&
        Math.abs(Color.green(pixel) - FROM_COLOR[1]) < THRESHOLD &&
        Math.abs(Color.blue(pixel) - FROM_COLOR[2]) < THRESHOLD;
}
```

Above code will change the color to transparent and below code will split the bitmap into 9 same size bitmaps:

```
public void splitBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ArrayList<Bitmap> smallimages = new ArrayList<>(9);
        int width, height;
        // Divide the original bitmap width by the desired vertical column count
        width = bitmap.getWidth() / 3;
        // Divide the original bitmap height by the desired horizontal row count
        height = bitmap.getHeight() / 3;
        // Loop the array and create bitmaps for each coordinate
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; ++x) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 3; ++y) {
                // Create the sliced bitmap
                smallimages.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, x * width, y * height, width, height));
            }
        }
    }
```

At last, you can use `PorterDuffColorFilter` on every bitmap:

```
    imageView.setImageDrawable(arrayList.get(0));
    imageView.setColorFilter(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

There can be problems as it works for me and might not for you but this is the way you can achieve your needed result.
If any problem persists, I can help.

Comment: Although, I had to change `Drawable` to `Bitmap` as your `splitBitmap` needs `Bitmap` and `adjust` returns a Drawable but your code helped me. Thanks +1.