# I'm using a recycler view in android studio and each item has a drawable. how can i change the color of drawable by clicking on a particular position?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

```
 public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public ImageView img_FurnishIamge;
        public FontTextView tv_FurnishText;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            img_FurnishIamge=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_furnishessImage);
            tv_FurnishText=(FontTextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_furnishesText);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int pos=getAdapterPosition();
                    switch (pos){
                        case 0:
                            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "00000", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "11111", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "22222", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "33333", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "44444", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "55555", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "66666", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }); //applying clickListner to the Item.
        }
```

Comment: Have u check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309629/how-to-change-colors-of-a-drawable-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the color of a image in an ImageView like this

```
ColorFilter filter = new LightingColorFilter(Color.BLACK, Color.parseColor("yourcolorcode"));
imageView.setColorFilter(filter );
```